# If my snake dies going downward or upward, it continues the upward/downward after restart. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a snake game.
I made the movement and I added a die function so when the character hits the border, dies.
If the character dies going downward or upward, when it restart, the character continues the upward/downward movement.
When it dies going to the left or right, it restarts as it should.
HTML and Javascript:

```js
var upDown = 0,
  rightLeft = 0;
var k, move, character;

window.onload = function() {
  move = setInterval(right, 10);
  character = document.getElementById('character');
  setInterval(die, 10);
}
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
  k = event.keyCode;
}

function die() {
  if (rightLeft > 1465 || rightLeft < 0 || upDown > 650 || upDown < 0) {
    clearInterval(move);
    upDown = 0;
    rightLeft = 0;
    character.style.left = 0 + "px";
    character.style.top = 0 + "px";
    move = setInterval(right, 10);
    alert("You lost!");
  }
}

function right() {
  rightLeft++;
  character.style.left = rightLeft + 'px';
  if (k == 38) {
    console.log(move);
    clearInterval(move);
    console.log(move);
    move = setInterval(up, 10);
  } else if (k == 40) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(down, 10);
  }
}

function left() {
  rightLeft--;
  character.style.left = rightLeft + "px";
  if (k == 38) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(up, 10);
  } else if (k == 40) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(down, 10);
  }
}

function down() {
  upDown++;
  character.style.top = upDown + "px";
  if (k == 39) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(right, 10);
  } else if (k == 37) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(left, 10);
  }
}

function up() {
  upDown--;
  character.style.top = upDown + "px";
  if (k == 39) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(right, 10);
  } else if (k == 37) {
    clearInterval(move);
    move = setInterval(left, 10);
  }
}
```

```css
#character {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}

#playGround {
  position: relative;
  background-color: gray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  width: 1515px;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div id="playGround">
  <div id="character"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I formatted your code and gave a better title

Comment: too much to explain and fix, see: https://repl.it/@lcherone/SNAKE

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of work to be done here, but as for your specific question: you forgot to reset the 'k' variable. Add the line `k = 0` to the `die()` function.
Good luck!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
For example adding code that does work can help.